# Maven use resources from other modules?

Tags: java, maven

how can I use resources from other maven modules? My goal is to provide a `AbstractImportClass` as well as the to be imported files in a specific maven module. And use this module within other modules extending this class.

Let's say `ModuleA` contains `src/main/java/MyAbstractImportClass.java`, and `src/main/resources/MyImport.csv`

I now want to use the abstract import class in `ModuleB`. Or rather, I will extend it, use the abstract-fileimport, and a few custom functions.
Then `ModuleC` also uses the abstracts' import and some custom functions.

The problem is: the import in abstract class goes with `reader` and `InputStream`. When I execute just ModuleA everything is fine.

But when I tried to include the module via maven pom, and then extend the module to call the import, then I get `NullPointerException` at the line where the reader is used.

So obvious I cannot use foreign module resources this way.

But how could I instead make use of this?

---

Update:

Module A:

```
src/main/java/path/to/MyClassA.java
src/main/resources/path/to/test.txt

abstract class MyClassA {
    public static String TESTFILE = test.txt;

    List<String> doImport(String filename) {
        InputStream fileStream = resourceClass.getResourceAsStream(filename);
        //some precessing
        return list;
    }
}
```

Module B:

```
src/main/java/path/to/MyClassB.java

class MyClassB implements MyClassA {
    List<String> list = doImport(TESTFILE);
}
```

If I put MyClassB in same dir as A, then everything works fine.
If I build B in a own module I get NullPointer for InputStream, what means the file is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your problem is related to Maven at all. [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) resolves relative paths as relative to the class object that you call it on. Therefore, if you use that method in an abstract class, every subclass of it could be looking for the resource in a different place.

For example, given three classes:

Super:

```
package com.foo;
public class Super {
    { System.out.println(getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.properties")); }
}
```

Sub1, a subclass of Super:

```
package com.foo.bar;
import com.foo.Super;
public class Sub1 extends Super {}
```

Sub2, another subclass:

```
package com.foo.bar.baz;
import com.foo.Super;
public class Sub2 extends Super {}
```

If you create a Super, it'll look for the classpath resource "/com/foo/test.properties" because that's how the path "test.properties" resolves relative to the class com.foo.Super. If you create a Sub1, it'll look instead in "/com/foo/bar/test.properties", and for a Sub2 instance, it'll look in "/com/foo/bar/baz/test.properties".

You might want to use an absolute path to the resource instead of a relative one, or else have the subclasses specify paths relative to themselves. It depends on your design and what kind of abstraction you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, so my absolute path would be: `de/my/path/to/Super/test.properties`? or with beginning `/de/my...`? It would be sufficient abstraction if the Super class can fetch the file that is contained in its appropriate resources/path/to/file folder.

Comment: Could be full path starting with / or relative path starting with location of your "resourceClass"

Comment: Yes, absolute classpath paths start with a '/'. If you want to use a relative path from Super, just be sure to use `Super.class.getResourceAsStream()` and not `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`. The latter is polymorphic, the former not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what your code does. Could you provide sample of how you're reading resource? If you do it properly - by getting InputStream from resource file in classpath there should be no problem. You can start by checking that ModuleA.jar has your resource file inside.

Comment: update above with some pseude code. I too think there shouldn't be a problem, but obv there is. And I even don't know if I could do it this way at all.

Comment: Could be absolute path starting with / or relative path starting with location of your "resourceClass".

Answer (score 0):

You should check:

1. Module B depend on Module A in pom.xml
2. The passed in 'filename' parameter starts with a '/', that is to say, the 'filename' parameter is '/path/to/test.txt' other than 'path/to/test.txt'

You program should work if these two conditions is satisfield.